# I want to catch reconnect event on client side in socket.io

Tags: node.js, socket.io, socket.io-1.0

Hello I did search a lot.
Can anybody please guide me on how to catch reconnect event in socketio.
So that I display a proper message on chat window.

I did try,but not working.

```
socket = io.connect(connectionString);


socket.on('reconnect', function(){

    alert("reconnected");
});

socket.reconnect(function(){
    alert("function reconnect called.");

});

socket.reconnecting(function(){
    alert("heloo");

});
```

Comment: What version of socket.io are you using?

Comment: @mscdex Can you tell me  what is the right way to test as well

Comment: `reconnecting` is an event, not a method. Also I doubt calling `reconnect()` will do much (if anything) if there is already a (re)connect in progress...

Answer (score 0):

There is a `reconnecting` event as noted in the [socket.io client documentation](http://socket.io/docs/client-api/#socket).

Comment: Can you tell me what is the right way to test as well